# 2 questions on basic linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I have 2 questions on from a practise linear algebra exam, and their the only 2 i couldnt figure out myself.

1. The solution set of A**x**=**b** is  always a translation of the solution set of A**x**=**0**. True or false?

I think the answer is False because you have to consider if there isn't any solutions to Ax=b, in which case it's the solution set is empty. Can someone confirm?

2. Let

A = [1  -1]  B = [0   1]  **v** = [2]

```
  [-1 1]    [2 1]    [1]
```

Let S : R^2 -> R^2 be the linear transformation with standard matrix A and let T : R^2 -> R^2 be the linear transformation with standard matrix B

Find a vector **w** in R^2 with the property that S(T(**w**)) = T(S(**w**))

I dont think we ever learned how to solve a question like this. I tried thinking about it and putting random vectors i thought would work, but i dont think thats the right way to do it, so I'd reaaally appreciate help on this one. Also tell me if the format for the matrixes are confusing and maybe i can figure out a better way to get them across

Comment: It's good that you're thinking the problems through, but I would lean towards True on the first one.  If I have a particular solution to Ax=b, the set of all solutions is found by translating by the solutions to Ax=0, right?  If there is no solution to Ax=b then there's not much to translate.

Comment: For 2, why not? If I put w to be the zero vector, it works. If you want to find all such w, you might want to find to find the kernel of the 2x2 matrix (AB-BA), that is, solving (AB-BA)(x)=0. If you have learnt matrix multiplication corresponds to composition, you shall know why you want to do that.

Comment: Li Chun Min, Putting 0 in is so obvious!!! I have no idea why i didnt think of that. Thanks! 

Sharding, i guess that also makes sense. I think the questions just worded weirdly because i could see it going both ways in my head. 

Thanks for the answers!!!!!

Comment: @Keeyan Although it seems obvious, i came up with "zero" after understanding the notions of "vector space" and "linear transformations". I did prove by def that linear transformations must map zero to zero :P

Comment: You define $v$ in question 2, then the question doesn't refer to it. Are you sure you have the question right?